# Extending a class by namespace

Tags: vb.net

I have a class within a library, with no root namespace, firstone.dll:

```
namespace first
    public partial class one
        public sub fun()

        end sub
    end class
end namespace
```

My second library, with no root namespace, firstonetwo.dll, references firstone.dll:

```
namespace first.one
   public partial class two
       public sub testfun()
            first.one.fun() 'not recognized'
       end sub
   end class
end namespace
```

or

```
namespace first
   public partial class one
        public partial class two
            public sub testfun()
                 first.one.fun() 'also not recognized'
            end sub
        end class
   end class
end namespace
```

Is there a way to extend the class in a separate dll and still have access to the original class? I don't want to inherit the class just extend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have a namespace and a class with the same name and that causes a lot of confusion. Your first example is a class called `one` in the `first` namespace and your second example is a class called `two` in the `first.one` namespace. Just because they can be written the same, there's big difference between the two.

[Do not name a class the same as its namespace, Part One](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx)

**EDIT**

Your tree looks something like this:

- first (ns)

  - one (class)
  - fun (method)
  - one (ns)
  - two (class)

VB is having a problem walking the tree and determining which `one` to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "Extension Methods" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx

This is the only form of 'extension' possible without inheriting.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested

```
namespace first 
    public partial class one 
        public overridable sub fun() 

        end sub 
    end class 
end namespace
```

Separate CLASS File

```
Imports first
namespace one 
   public partial class fun 
        public overrides sub fun() 

        end sub 
   end class 
end namespace
```